# Trying to set Drawable android:topLeftRadius, android:bottomLeftRadius but the view is different on different devices

Tags: android

I am trying to use drawable XML file as a button background. I want to achieve

[image]

But when I write that code:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/button_radius"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/button_stroke_width"
        android:color="@color/colorBlack"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:startColor="@color/colorLightPurple"
        android:endColor="@color/colorDeepPurple" />
    </shape>
```

I get that shape on phone:

[image]

When I changed code to:

```
<corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

I got the shape that I what but on tablets shape is not that I want.
Any one could give me an advice what could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this same shape in my app but with drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/log_btn_cancel"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

I use it in a LinearLayout with clickable set as TRUE, and works just perfect in every single device I have tested.

hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but my business logic is to change button text when it is pressed. I tried whit TextView but didn't work. I am using API 11. Do you thing that could be a problem?